# Multiple instances of static or global through linking

Tags: c++

I have run into a situation where some dependency code is a static library.

Let's call it static library "A".
I have made a dll "B" and it links to "A".
And an executable "C" links to both.

```
I think this diagram is correct:

            A  static lib
           / \
          |   B   dll
           \   \
            \---C  executable
```

"A" contains a logger class that uses global variables. It's one of those your company hands you, you look at it, and say to yourself, "oh crap what a mess."

It appears that those global variables in "A" have different addresses depending on whether I am stepping through code in the executable module or stepping through the code in the dll module.

This, of course, makes the logger behave in an unexpected manner.

I assume the static library was copied once into the dll and once into the executable and there are therefore actually 2 copies of all statics and globals. Is that correct?

The second part of the question is, will making this logger a Meyer's singleton solve the problem or will a static in method scope also have different addresses depending which module I call from?

Or, is the proper thing to do, making all 50 some projects link dynamically if one links dynamically?

Comment: @descherjm Yes. they are all part of the same solution in Visual Studio 2015. The solution has one executable into which all are linked.

Comment: Can you put the global variables in a dll?

Comment: @dresherjm Not in any amount of time that my superiors would be happy with.

Comment: A singleton in a static library will not solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every executable that logs must currently have linked in the static library.  Note that a DLL is considered to be an executable here.

Therefore, both your DLL and your EXE have their own copy of said static library, with their own variables and so forth.  Your only real recourse is to move logging from a static library to a DLL, or make it so that multiple instances logging at once works in a useful and expected manner.

Comment: You believe the Meyer's pattern will have the same undesired behavior? i.e. what about statics at method scope?

Comment: Yes.  You could get around it by instantiating a singleton COM object (then it could be shared correctly), but that's no easier than just making a logging DLL.